# SQL aggregation with where

Tags: sqlite

We have the following table:
| name | legs | weight|
|------|------|-------|
|bird  |2     |6      |
|cat   |4     |10     |
|dog   |4     |20     |
|ferret|4     |10     |
|penguin|2    |10      |
|t-rex  |2     |12000      |
and if I run the first query:

```
select min(legs), max(weight), name from animals;
```

the result is:
| min(legs) | max(weight) | name|
|------|------|-------|
|2  |12000     |t-rex      |
and if I run the second query in which I add a where condition:

```
select min(legs), max(weight), name from animals where name <> "t-rex";
```

the result is:
| min(legs) | max(weight) | name|
|------|------|-------|
|2  |20    |dog      |

I don't understand why in second case name is dog. My understanding is that we exclude t-rex row, and do query from the rest of rows. Then we select min of legs, which is 2, max of weight, which is 20. And apparently min of legs 2 and max of weight 20 are not in the same row.

Comment: What name do you expect to get from the query?

Answer (score 0):

**name** as it ism, is a [bare column](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) and will be an arbitrary **name**

- You might also want to skip back to the preceding section [2.4. Generation of the set of result rows](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#generation_of_the_set_of_result_rows)

Examples to get around the issue (assuming you want the max weight of animals with 2 legs but not t-rex) :-

```
SELECT legs,weight,name 
FROM animals 
WHERE name <> 't-rex' 
ORDER BY legs ASC, weight DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM animals WHERE legs = (SELECT min(legs) FROM animals))
SELECT legs,weight,name 
FROM cte 
WHERE name <> 't-rex' 
ORDER BY weight 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Which both result in:-

[image]